# How to show the auth page if the URL doesn't contain extra path?

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I use Spring security plugin for our Grails application.
How to show the authentication page if the user typed the URL without any extra path, for example:

http://localhost:8080/OurGrails

I use Config.groovy file to specify URL constraints:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/zoning/*': ['ROLE_USER'],
    '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be `'/': ['ROLE_USER']` and in some containers might also require `'/index.gsp': ['ROLE_USER']`.

Comment: Thanks. In Tomcat it is '/' .